# Error in converting a MOV video into MP4 using ffmpeg

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I want to convert a mov video into mp4 using ffmpef library of php.
I am using given code:

```
$cmd='ffmpeg -i sample.mov -sameq output.mp4';
echo exec($cmd);
```

It is not working at all. Even I didn't get any error. Could anyone tell me the proper steps to do this conversion. I have tried a lot of code examples but not working for me.

Comment: Did you find a solution? What error were you getting? It seems you need to go via mpegts first

Answer (score 0):

use `-qscale 0` instead of `-sameq`.

Comment: `-qscale` is ignored by libx264 which, if available, is the default encoder for MP4 output. Use `-crf` instead if using this encoder.